# Select the Enum dynamically

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have three enums `Country_INDIA, Country_USA,Country_AUSTRALIA`. At runtime, the `country name` is decided  (could be one of INDIA or USA or AUSTRALIA). Is there a way I can pick the right enum based on the country name at runtime. For example, if the country name is `USA` , I want to pick **Country_USA** enum.

```
enum Country_INDIA {

  INTREST_RATE = '10%',
  MIN_INVESTMENT_DURATION = "5YRS"

};

enum Country_USA {

  INTREST_RATE = '3%',
  MIN_INVESTMENT_DURATION = "3YRS"
};

enum Country_AUSTRALIA {

  INTREST_RATE = '5%',
  MIN_INVESTMENT_DURATION = "2YRS"
};

let country_enum = "Country_"+"USA" 

console.log(country_enum.INTREST_RATE); // get the interst rate from 'Country_USA' enum
```

Comment: *interest rate...

Comment: There's no TS-approved way to programmatically access variables by name, but you could package your enums in a namespace so they are properties, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mLOPZN). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using enums is not the optimal way to solve your case:
a map would be easier

```
const countryData = {
  USA: {
    INTEREST_RATE = 10,
    MIN_INVESTMENT_DURATION = "5YRS"
  },
  UK: {
    INTEREST_RATE = 1,
    MIN_INVESTMENT_DURATION = "10YRS"
  }

};

const interestRate = countryData['USA'].INTEREST_RATE; // 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the enums available to JavaScript

```js
enum CountryINDIA {
  INTEREST_RATE = '10%',
    MIN_INVESTMENT_DURATION = "5YRS"
}

enum CountryUSA {
  INTEREST_RATE = '3%',
    MIN_INVESTMENT_DURATION = "3YRS"
}

enum CountryAUSTRALIA {
  INTEREST_RATE = '5%',
    MIN_INVESTMENT_DURATION = "2YRS"
}

// Create a mapping object
const countries = {
  Country_INDIA: CountryINDIA,
  Country_USA: CountryUSA,
  Country_AUSTRALIA: CountryAUSTRALIA,
};

// Now you can dynamically access the enums
let countryName = "Country_USA";
let countryEnum = countries[countryName];

if (countryEnum) {
  console.log(countryEnum.INTEREST_RATE); // Outputs: 3%
} else {
  console.log("Country not found");
}
```

Alternatively don't use an enum, a POJO will be simpler.